# Does differentiability on an open set imply differentiability on a compact set?

Tags: calculus, analysis

If I have a function $f(x) \in C^\infty$ for $x \in (-\epsilon,+\epsilon)$. Can I find a compact set in $(-\epsilon,+\epsilon)$ where $f(x)$ is also $\in C^\infty$? I need this information to imply that $f(x)$ is bounded in that compact set, so it takes it´s maximum/minimum.

Comment: You just need continuity. You don't need differentiability. Take the compact set $[-\varepsilon/2,\varepsilon/2]$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams So I can imply that $f(x)$ is continuous on $[-\epsilon/2,\epsilon/2]$ and therefore bounded?

Comment: Yep that's exactly right!

Comment: @CameronWilliams Thank you very much.

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question if you'd like :) That way it will not get bumped later for not having an answer. You can accept it two days later.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I tried:) Would you please take a look if it's correct/clear? And I just explained it, did not prove it.

Comment: Looks good! Great work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if a function $f(x)$ is continuous differentiable on an open set $(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$ then there exists an compact set such as $[-\epsilon/2,\epsilon/2]$ in which $f(x)$ is continuously bounded and takes its maximum.